# add totals to barchart tooltip in echarts4r

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, tooltip, echarts

I am trying to create a custom tooltip that in `echarts4r`, shows in an addition  to the values of the different stacks, also shows the total (equal to the height of the bar): so something like this (from [chart.js: Place tooltip for stacked bar charts on top of bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166613/chart-js-place-tooltip-for-stacked-bar-charts-on-top-of-bar)):

[image]

This codes just misses the totals

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.frame(a =letters[1:10],
                 x = rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd = 5), 
                 y = rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd = 5),
                 z = rnorm(10, mean = 10, sd = 5))

dt %>% 
  mutate(total = x +y +z) %>%
  e_charts(a) %>%
  e_bar(x, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_bar(y, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_bar(z, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_grid(containLabel = T) %>%
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
```

This code shows the data somewhat OK, but does not have the right labels and is not as pleasing to look at (for example misses the colour code)

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(total = x +y +z) %>%
  e_charts(a) %>%
  e_bar(x, stack = "stack",  bind = total) %>%
  e_bar(y, stack = "stack",  bind = total) %>%
  e_bar(z, stack = "stack",  bind = total) %>%
  e_grid(containLabel = T) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                        function(params)
                                        {
                                            return `<strong>${params.value[0]}</strong>
                                                      <br/>    ${params.value[1]}
                                                    <br/>Total: ${params.name}`
                                        }  "))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52704832/12993861) this could be achieved like so:

Note: Additionally I slightly increased the width, right aligned the numbers and computed the total inside the formatter function.

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.frame(a =letters[1:10],
                 x = rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd = 5), 
                 y = rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd = 5),
                 z = rnorm(10, mean = 10, sd = 5))

dt %>% 
  e_charts(a) %>%
  e_bar(x, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_bar(y, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_bar(z, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_grid(containLabel = T) %>%
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis", formatter = htmlwidgets::JS('
                                                          function (params) {
            let tooltip = `<p style="width: 100px;">${params[0].axisValue}</p>`;
            let total = 0
            params.forEach(({ seriesName, marker, value }) => {
              value = value || [0, 0];
              tooltip += `<p style="width: 100px;">${marker} ${seriesName}<span style="float: right;"><strong>${value[1]}</strong></span></p>`;
              total += Number(value[1]);
            });
            
            tooltip += `<p style="width: 100px;">Total<span style="float: right;"><strong>${total}</strong></span>`;
            
            return tooltip;
          }'))
```

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to add  a "biq mark" notations for big numbers i.e. (1'000'00) with this superb solution (and maybe also how to control the number of decimals) ?